# JUnit Categorie will not run certain tests

Tags: java, junit, categories, powermock

I have a project with tests. I have the AllTests class set up with `Suite` runner for every package, and I have a master `AllTest` that aggregates all the other `AllTest` classes. The master is also ran by `Suite`.

I defined an interface `IntegrationTest` and also an `IntegrationTestSuite` class. `IntegrationTestSuite` is ran by `Categories` and as a `SuiteClass`, I specify the master `AllTests`, also added `IncludeCategory` annotation with `IntegrationTest.class`. In a couple of tests, I use the annotation `@Category(IntegrationTest.class)` on the class level to include some of the tests in the integration suite.

I have a couple of test classes that are run be `PowerMockRunner` and also annotation by `@Category(IntegraionTest.class)`. My problem is basically, some of these tests are executed by my Gradle build and some are just skipped. If I remove the `PrepareForTest` annotation for the skipped tests, I receive an error message that powermock was not sep up correctly and these error messages show up in the report as well, otherwise it's just silence.

The strange thing about this is, for a short period of time, when I ran the same suite in Eclipse, it was able to find and run those tests gradle skipped. But after a while, the Eclipse JUnit runner also forgot about those tests and now it will not run them, when running the suite. If I run these tests directly, they run successfully.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong, or where can I check things out what is going wrong? Using the gradle --stacktrace or --debug switches did not help, there were no info in the output about these tests.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I mentioned I use PowerMock in the tests. Turns out, PowerMockRunner loads the IntegrationTest interface class with another classloader, than the classloader of the suite. This was, junit's isAssignableFrom test will fail when determining what tests to run. -> Missing one entry from @PowerMockIgnore.